# Redirecting all requests on one domain to https non-www

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have an ISPConfig 3 site running on one domain. I have multiple vhost files for the different applications I run through Apache. I want to enable https://example.com/%QUERY_STRING% on every request that come through Apache with that domain. Right now, I have to paste

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule . https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule . https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

in every one of my vhosts. If I had to do this once, it wouldn't be a problem, but I constantly wipe my server and rebuild it from scratch (I have good reasons). I don't like going through all the vhosts and pasting this in every one, I know there must be a more technical way to do this. I tried putting this in my `apache2.conf` but this does not work. Also I can't turn on SSLEngine unless we are in a `<Location>` or `<Directory>` or something like that.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in your `apache2.conf`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com$1 [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: What happened ? Do you have rewrite log ? What is your 443 port virtual host configuration ?

Comment: It seems that this code is good inside the virtualhost, not in `apache2.conf`. Moving this into `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:443>` works. Thanks!